# jquery/js syntax array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

I have a web page which is using below syntax . Its generating a table using array . Can anyone explain what the {#arrayOfObjects} means and where it came from(jquery or js)?

```
{{#arrayOfObjects}}
    <tr>
        <td class="some1">{{name}}</td>
        <td class="some2">{{label}}</td>
        <td class="{{some3}}">{{age}}</td>
    </tr>
{{/arrayOfObjects}}
```

Comment: This is not javascript, it is templating language, probably [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/).

Comment: ya ..i got it ..its Mustache template language syntax ..thx for the clue ..

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be part of some sort of HTML template and the code parsing the template is expanding that block of HTML into a series of HTML rows in a table using the `arrayOfObjects` variable that was passed into the template rendering as the data for the rows.

This is not actual HTML, this is a template formatted file.  The output of the template rendering will be actual HTML.

This is a guess, but it looks like it might be a [handlebars template](http://handlebarsjs.com/) or [mustache template](http://mustache.github.io/) or one of the other similar template engines that are all derived from the same basic scheme.

Comment: @JavaUser - Did this answer your question?  If so, please indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer.  If not, then please explain what you still need help with.